# Absorption spectrum of common plastic polymers

Tags: polymers, plastics, absorption

I am looking for data regarding absorption spectrum of common used plastic polymers, in the range of 200- 1.000 nm
Moreover, I am looking for inorganic or organic compounds, which can be mixed together with common plastics (PC, ABS, PMMA, POM) and have an absorption peak at 450 nm

Comment: Do you want only around (or about) 450 nm or would something like [this](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/133911/79678) be acceptable?

Comment: It seems both question can be entries for a search. Ex: absorption spectra of pmma.

Comment: What @EdV suggests would be fine. We need different polymers, not only PMMA

Comment: @Francesco my meaning was that first you search and than eventually come here to ask.

Comment: @Alchimista, I can assure I did extensive search. As I wrote I am not interested only in the absorption spectra of the different polymers, but also in knowing if there is any special compound with a strong absorbance of light around 450 nm.